# Why to make a class abstract when you can extend and instantiate it?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstraction

I am confused. I got excited when I got to know that abstract basically means the class is hidden and no one can instantiate it. Cool. But when I got to know that someone can come and extend to my class and just instantiate it, use all the methods, what is the point of making a class abstract when someone can just steal all your qualities, act like you and sell himself in the market.

If anyone could help me with explaining this, I would be grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by _"someone can just steal all your qualities, act like you and sell himself in the market"_? In what market? Using abstract classes is an implementation detail in your application (except if you are providing a library / framework) and not something that is meant to somehow "protect your application from stealing"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent others from inheriting from your class make it `final`. But than its the last of its hierarchy, so it can no longer be inherited and so to be declared `abstract` (because its obsolete).
Abstract classes are templates. They inherit properties and functions without implementing them concretely (you can of course give a default behavior for all, but the idea behind `abstract` in a declared method is to be `abstract` -> not implemented) and only serve to build up a hierarchy. Example:

```
abstract class Vehicle {...}
class Car extends Vehicle {...}
class Bike extends Vehicle {...}
```

`Vehicle` descibes common properties but a concret instantiation is too vague. We call all types of vehicles 'Vehicle', even if we never have seen one of them purely in nature. It's a thought construct that makes it easier to classify concrete forms like a car or a bike.

Comment: Thanks! That last para helped a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class basically means **hiding the implementation details and showing only functionality to the user**.

Abstract class can have following  method.

1. Abstract Method
2. Non Abstract Method
   After Java 8 they can also have
3. static method
4. final method

   Abstract class A{

   abstract void run();  //Abstract Method

   }

   class B extends A{

   void run(){
   System.out.println("running safely");
   }

   }

Above you can see run() method doesn't have any implementation in class A.

It cannot be instantiated because of this only as there is no implementation of run() in class A

so to make it work it need to be extended and implemented (that's what done in class B).

In outer world people can only see run()  they will not able to get how run works
or actual implementation of run() method.

refer this link for more information: [abstract class in java](https://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are not hidden. Abstract classes are **"incomplete"** classes which can be "completed" in many different ways. If you have classes that contain a lot of similar code, it may be a good idea to move all the similar code into the abstract class and make your classes extend this abstract class.

Abstract classes are otherwise quite full-featured. They can have constructors even, despite the fact that you can't instantiate them. These constructors can be called via the `super` keyword from child class constructors:

```
abstract class Parent {
    private String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    private boolean hasMilkTeeth;

    public Child(String name, boolean hasMilkTeeth) {
        super(name); // calls the parent constructor!
        this.hasMilkTeeth = hasMilkTeeth;
    }

    public boolean hasMilkTeeth() {
        return hasMilkTeeth;
    }
}
```

Comment: The example could be better. Parent has no abstract methods and "Child / Parent" is also not a useful abstraction. You can't say a child "is a" parent. Being a child is a property of a person that could be defined by their age and may change over the lifetime of the object.

Comment: Good point, but I wanted to demonstrate `super`, and not a full-blown real-world class hierarchy.

Comment: "Abstract classes are not hidden. Abstract classes are "incomplete" classes which can be "completed" in many different ways." - this helped a lot